# using "Preprocessor Directives" in Named Query?

Tags: ssas

My question is that, can I use "Preprocessor Directives" in Named Query? (Like C#)

For example, I wish I wrote a Named Query (in Data Source for SSAS) is like bellow:

```
select * my table
#if DEBUG
where Date >= '2018-01-01'
#endif 
#else
where Date >= '2015-01-01'
#endif
```

if Configuration mode is set to "Development", getting data is '2018-01-01', '2018-01-02'...., and if Configuration mode is set to "Release", getting is '2015-01-01', '2015-01-02'....

Thanks for any possible solutions!

Comment: Just preprocess your code. Also `enfif`?

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake and updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first recommendation you may consider is to build SQL views and access the tables through those views. Then it should be easy to alter the views before processing the model in development.

If that doesn't meet your needs, then the following is pretty close to what you asked for. First, set the Application Name property on the data source connection string like this:

[image: Application Name connection string property]

Then changed the named query in the DSV to look something like this:

```
SELECT DateKey
FROM DimDate
where (app_name()='DEV' and DateKey >= 20060101)
or (app_name()='PROD' and DateKey >= 20040101)
```

[image: app_name() in the named query]

As you may have determined, the Configuration dropdown at the top of Visual Studio lets you switch between "Development" and "Production". And the connection string for each Visual Studio Configuration can differ as I blogged about [here](http://www.artisconsulting.com/blogs/greggalloway/2008/3/19/analysis-services-project-configurations). So I would recommend setting `Application Name=DEV` in the connection string under the Development configuration, and `Application Name=PROD` in the connection string under the Production configuration.

One note is that I have found Visual Studio doesn't always save the configurations to disk so any time you change a connection string for the Development or Production configuration, I would recommend right clicking on the Roles folder in Solution Explorer and choosing Add Role then immediately deleting it. That simple step is enough to make Visual Studio aware the project files need to be saved to disk.

Comment: Hi @GregGalloway,

Thank you for your reply. It meets my need perfectly.

I've learned by your answer that Application Name is configurable on each environment. So, I've tried to build my cube along with your tips, then, it works for the cube perfectly.

Thank you again for your answer!